# I can not add a node to the XML file within the right element

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, xmldocument

When I save a new Question element, I need it to be inside the questions element, which in turn is inside the QuestionCollection, but the way I'm saving the new elements are outside the questions and are not read later. 
How XML is getting:  (ABA IS NEW ELEMENT)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuestionCollection>
    <Question Titulo="ABA">
      <Enunciado>ABB</Enunciado>
      <Resposta1>ABC</Resposta1>
      <Resposta2>ABD</Resposta2>
      <Resposta3>ABE</Resposta3>
      <Resposta4>ABF</Resposta4>
      <RespostaC>ABC</RespostaC>
    </Question>
  <Questions>
    <START>
    </START>
    <Question Titulo="AAA">
      <Enunciado>AAB</Enunciado>
      <Resposta1>AAC</Resposta1>
      <Resposta2>AAD</Resposta2>
      <Resposta3>AAE</Resposta3>
      <Resposta4>AAF</Resposta4>
      <RespostaC>AAF</RespostaC>
    </Question>
  </Questions>
</QuestionCollection>
```

How should I stay:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QuestionCollection>
  <Questions>
    <START>
    </START>
    <Question Titulo="AAA">
      <Enunciado>AAB</Enunciado>
      <Resposta1>AAC</Resposta1>
      <Resposta2>AAD</Resposta2>
      <Resposta3>AAE</Resposta3>
      <Resposta4>AAF</Resposta4>
      <RespostaC>AAF</RespostaC>
    </Question>
    <Question Titulo="ABA">
      <Enunciado>ABB</Enunciado>
      <Resposta1>ABC</Resposta1>
      <Resposta2>ABD</Resposta2>
      <Resposta3>ABE</Resposta3>
      <Resposta4>ABF</Resposta4>
      <RespostaC>ABC</RespostaC>
    </Question>  
</Questions>
</QuestionCollection>
```

Part of Code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();
doc.Load ("Assets/Resources/Questions.xml");

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

XmlElement q = doc.CreateElement ("Question");
q.InnerText = Question;

XmlNode qa = doc.SelectSingleNode ("QuestionCollection/Questions/START");

root.InsertAfter(q,qa);

doc.Save ("Assets/Resources/Questions.xml");
Instance.CloseWindow ();
```

ERROR: ArgumentException: The reference node is not a child of this node.

Comment: breakpoint the SelectSingleNode part and ensure that it is selecting the correct node.  Also I'll note that in your code you have QuestionsCollection instead of QuestionCollection in the select singe node call

Comment: Which is your new node? "ABA" or "AAA"? Because your code is attempting to insert the new node after the "START" node. If you want it to add it to the end of the Questions node, `SelectSingleNode` the Questions node, and use `AppendChild`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Marshall Tigerus is correct, but there's more;

Change this:

```
XmlElement q = doc.CreateElement("Question");
q.InnerText = Question;

XmlNode qa = doc.SelectSingleNode("QuestionCollection/Questions");
XmlNode start = qa.SelectSingleNode("START");

qa.InsertAfter(q,start);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, I'd like to add attributes, elements ...?

Comment: `q.SetAttribute("id", "123");` and `q.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Answer"));`

Comment: And a value for element?

Comment: A value is just another node. Create a text node and use AppendChild

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you haven't put a typo in your code above, I think I know what is happening.

Your XML structure has QuestionCollection as an element, while your SelectSingleNode call has QuestionsCollection.  This will cause the qa node to be null.

The InsertAfter method has logic in it that will handle the reference node being null.  It will instead insert the new element as a child of the root element at the beginning of the list (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertafter(v=vs.110).aspx)

This appears to be what is happening here.  Remove that extra s from your SelectSingleNode parameters and you should be good.

Comment: ArgumentException: The reference node is not a child of this node.
System.Xml.XmlNode.CheckNodeInsertion (System.Xml.XmlNode newChild, System.Xml.XmlNode refChild)